# Magento 2 : Move to 'MY ORDERS' tab in MY DASHBOARD

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, blocks, magento-2.0

How I can move account  My orders list in Account dashboard ?  As My orders are on top at this time.

```
block block-dashboard-orders
```

what will be block name to move this ?

Answer (score -1):

Block name: customer_account_dashboard_top (Recent orders)

```
<move element="customer_account_dashboard_top" destination="content" before="customer_account_dashboard_info"/>
```